# Jquery does not catch unchecking of radio-button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, bootstrap-4, custom-data-attribute

I am builing a multi-step form.

Here is part of it:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="form-check">
    <input id="1-1" class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="firstRadioGroup">
    <label for="1-1">Radio button 1-1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input id="1-2" class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="firstRadioGroup" data-show="#textarea-1">
    <label for="1-2">Radio button 1-2</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <textarea name="textarea-1" id="textarea-1" cols="30" rows="10" style="display: none"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="form-check">
    <input id="2-1" class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="secondRadioGroup">
    <label for="2-1">Radio button 2-1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input id="2-2" class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="secondRadioGroup" data-show="#textarea-2">
    <label for="2-2">Radio button 2-2</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <textarea name="textarea-2" id="textarea-2" cols="30" rows="10" style="display: none"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="form-check">
    <input id="checkbox-1" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="secondRadioGroup">
    <label for="checkbox-1">Checkbox 1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input id="checkbox-2" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="secondRadioGroup">
    <label for="checkbox-2">Checkbox 2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input id="checkbox-other" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="secondRadioGroup"  data-show="#textarea-3">
    <label for="checkbox-other">Other</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <textarea name="textarea-3" id="textarea-3" cols="30" rows="10" style="display: none"></textarea>
</div>
```

And here is my JS :

```
$("[data-show]").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $($(this).data('show')).show();
    } else {
        $($(this).data('show')).hide();
    }
});
```

What's the problem:
With checkbox it works fine. Showing and hiding on checking/unchecking the checkbox.
With radio buttons it works fine on the show, but it's not hiding on changing from current group of radio buttons.

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v9kgugrc/18/)

EDIT 1:
What I need with radio button groups:
If I check radio-button with

```
name="radio_group_1" data-show="#id-of-textarea"
```

a textarea with

```
id="id-of-textarea"
```

shows up. If after this I check another radio-button from the same group

```
name="radio_group_1" NO DATA-ATTRIBUTE HERE
```

the textarea hides.

Comment: Check my answer below its working perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery logic is wrong. **Working:** https://jsfiddle.net/vutpcu0g/5

You should check the change event on all radios, not just the `data-show` ones. Then, select the nearest sibling radio to toggle the data-show element.

```
$("[type=radio],[type=checkbox]").change(function(){

    if($(this).is(":checked") && $(this).data("show")) {
    $($(this).data('show')).show();
  } else {
    var sib= $(this).parents('.form-group').find('[data-show]');
    $(sib.data("show")).hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks it does now

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your code.Use this script.

```
$("[type='radio']").change(function(){
$("[type='radio']").each(function(){
 if($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $($(this).data('show')).show();
  } else {
    $($(this).data('show')).hide();
  }
  });
});
```

Fiddle: https://codepen.io/smitraval27/pen/XEpGNR

In your code you have not given [data-show] to every radio button. Plus on change of radio you have to use each to find out the changes of each and every radio.